# How to show $\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=j+1}^\infty |\xi_n|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}=0.$

Tags: functional-analysis

So this may be a stupid question but...

I'm trying to find a subspace of $\ell^p$ that's not closed. I have the following

Let

$$\ell^p\supseteq X=\left\{\text{sequences with a finite number of non-zero elements}\right\}.$$

Let $x=\left(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...\right)\in \ell^p$ be a sequence with an infinite number of non-zero terms. Define the following sequence, $(x_j)\in X$ where
\begin{align*}
    {x_j}_n=
    \begin{cases}
        \xi_n&\text{if } j\leq n\\
        0&\text{if } j>n.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
We therefore find,
\begin{align*}
    \|x_j-x\|_p=\left(\sum_{n=1}^j|\xi_n-\xi_n|^p+\sum_{n=j+1}^\infty|-\xi_n|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}=\left(\sum_{n=j+1}^\infty |\xi_n|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}.
\end{align*}
Since $x\in \ell^p$, $\sum_{n=j+1}^\infty |\xi_n|^p$ converges by Subsequence Limit Theorem.

Intuitively, I sort of assume
$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=j+1}^\infty |\xi_n|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}=0.$$
However I'm not sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: It is an elementary fact that if $\sum a_n$ is a convergent series of positive terms then $\sum\limits_{k=j}^{\infty} a_k \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.